# Does $\mathsf{Man}$ possess countable products?

Tags: category-theory, manifolds, locally-convex-spaces

In our lecture we defined a category $\mathcal C$ to have arbitrary products, iff every diagram $A:\mathcal J \to \mathcal C$ with $\text{Morph}(\mathcal J)=\{\text{id}_j\}_{j \in Ob(\mathcal J)}$ has a limit. We showed that the category **Man** (with manifolds modelled on locally convex spaces) possesses finite products (i.e. $Ob(\mathcal J)$ finite), but argued that it does not possess infinite ones. As far as i can see, in defiance of this in the following we always use the product over $Ob(\mathcal J) = \mathbb N$.

My question is now: Is the infinite (countable) cartesian product of manifolds still a manifold? If not, what is the problem? Does the category of locally convex spaces **Lcs** possess arbitrary products?

Comment: Is your question about the existence of countable products in $\mathsf{Man}$, or is it about the creation of countable products of the forgetful functor to $\mathsf{Top}$? The latter is easy to disprove.

Comment: It's about countable products in **Man**, even though i don't understand what you mean with creation of products of the forgetful functor.

Comment: Well, the question "is the product of manifolds a manifold" doesn't really make sense, since products in an arbitrary category - by definition - are objects of that category. The question is only: do they exist? But usually when people ask something like this, they actually mean something stronger, namely if the products exist *and* the underlying space is just the usual product of the spaces. So the question is: If we have a countable family of manifolds, can we endow the product of the underlying spaces with the structure of a manifold? Probably almost never.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I suspect the OP is asking about possibly-infinite-dimensional manifolds, given the mention of "locally convex spaces".

Comment: Hmm, i think it is possible for (cartesian) products of manifolds modelled on normed vector spaces. Take for example $\prod_{\mathbb N} \mathbb S^1$. It is clear that $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ is a locally convex space due to the point-seperating family of semi-norms $p_n((x_i)_{i\in \mathbb N})=|x_n|$. Then one can define the charts canonically, right?

Comment: My intuition is that there is no locally convex modelled manifold which would be the product of the family ${\mathbb N}_0\times\{\,{\mathbb S}^{\,1}\}\,$. If there were one such $M$ with the projections $p_i:M\to\mathbb S^{\,1}$, then considering the maps $f_i:\mathbb R\to\mathbb S^{\,1}$ given by $t\mapsto{\rm e}\,^{i\,2\,\pi\,{\rm i}\,t}$ one would get existence of a (at least continuous) map $f:\mathbb R\to M$ with $p_i\circ f=f_i$. So given any neigbourhood $V$ in $M$ of $f(0)$, there would exist a neighbourhood $U$ in $\mathbb R$ of $0$ with $f[U]\subseteq V$. (cont.)

Comment: At the present, I cannot see the details, but I think this should somehow lead to a contradiction by noting that $f_i$ goes "very fast" around $\mathbb S^{\,1}$ when $i$ becomes large.